# Name for the $\otimes$ operator

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, vectors

I'm teaching 3D vector stuff to engineers.

When we write $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}$, we say "u dot v".

When we write $\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v}$, we say "u cross v".

When we write $\mathbf{u} \otimes \mathbf{v}$, we say what??

Here $\mathbf{u} \otimes \mathbf{v}$ is the so-called "[outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product)", defined by $\mathbf{u} \otimes \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^T$. It's clumsy and verbose to say "the outer product of u and v" and it feels odd to say "u outer v". Any ideas?

Comment: Usually this symbol is called "tensor", e.g. "$u$ tensor $v$".

Comment: This is a special case of the _much_ more general, so-called _tensor product_, so calling it "u tensor v" is not wrong.

Comment: I've heard it pronounced as "u bun v". I believe the mental image is  a [hot cross bun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_cross_bun) as viewed from above.